# Only allow negative sign as first character in "number" type input box

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Is there a way only allow a negative sign (or hyphen) for the first character in an input tag of type "number"? It has to be type "number" so that the correct keyboard appears on mobile. However, a user can still enter multiple negative signs before clicking "Submit". I have used `.checkValidity()`, which helps, but prevents entering a negative sign in the first place unless I type a number first. I can't validate with `.value`, since that returns a blank if it is invalid.

HTML

```
<input type="number" id="input">
```

JavaScript

```
var input = document.querySelector('#input');
var value;

input.oninput = function() { 
    if (input.checkValidity()) {
        value = input.value;
    }
    else{
        input.value = value;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you considered it may not be a great idea? Your users may very well *paste* a number. If they unfortunately also have copied some extra text or even just a space, then your script will just discard everything, when they could have corrected their input otherwise. IMM the best is to let your user know it's invalid, but don't wipe it out automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```html
<input type="number" id="input" oninput="this.value.match(/^-?\d*\.?\d*$/)||(this.value='');">
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not allow someone to enter the negative sign first.

Comment: @Max I modified my answer. See if it's what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom Regexp to test input. Only one hyphen at the begining will be allowed.

```
/^[-0-9][0-9]+$/.test(input)
```

So the code block may be

```
input.oninput = function() { 
  if (/^[-0-9][0-9]+$/.test(input.value)) {
      value = input.value;
  }
  else{
      input.value = value;
  }
}
```

I have not tested but I think that would help.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work because when you use .value on an input field of type "number" it only gets the valid numeric value, not the whole text, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex that matches nothing but digits then check for matches and set the input value accordingly, on input.

```js
const el = document.querySelector('#myInput');
el.value = '-';

el.addEventListener('input', e => {
  const m = e.target.value.match(/\d+/g);
  el.value = m === null ? '-' : `-${m}`;
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" />
```

Comment: That would work with a "text" type, but I need it for a "number" type, and JS won't get the value until there is a valid number.

Comment: What do you mean JS won't get the value? It most definitely will... I understand it's a text type but it only allows you to type numbers which you can just do `Number(val)`

Answer (score 0):

The [`pattern`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) HTML attribute is pretty well [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern) these days, so you might use it for this validation.

Try to play with the form in the snippet below -- if the value is not a number, a tooltip appears and the form won't submit. **No JS**.

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="number" id="input" pattern="^-?\d+$">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

To validate while user is inputting, you'll need JS:

```css
input:invalid {background:#f009}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="number" id="input" pattern="^-?\d+$" oninput="this.checkValidity()">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but unfortunately, I need it to validate immediately, not when it is being submitted. I tried this, and it does not check the regular expression until a real number is entered.